# How did the Wraith get through the iris in "Midway"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

I noticed that when the Wraith originally send their stun device, the Stargate is activated with a Midway IDC. Then, Walter *manually* opens the iris. Then the Stargate shuts down.

How did the Wraith get their warriors past the iris? If they re-dialled Earth, then nobody could open the iris in response to their valid IDC as they were all unconscious.

Comment: For better answers I would recommend posting the episode you are referring to as well with your description... but honestly the writers are not perfect. Chalk it up to a lapse in judgement on the part of the writers... or you could say that (since the Wraith are intelligent) they either hacked the system or drug Walter's hand up to the sensor before throwing him aside...

Comment: They can't drag it, since none of them are present at the time. Also, "Midway" is the name of the episode.

Comment: haha Very true! good point! I'm gonna say they hacked it... I would have to watch it again though to see anything else.

Comment: It's been a couple years since I rewatched it last BUT, IIRC, the iris was closed manually after a wormhole was established. With few exceptions, it largely remained open when the gate wasn't active. I vaguely recall exchanges in which a technician announced an incoming wormhole and was ordered to close the iris-fairly frequently. When the Wraith invaded, Walter opened the iris because of the Midway IDC and was then knocked unconscious so he couldn't close it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iris is not automated likely because an automatic system could conceivably be hacked from off world as well as an automated system would not be able to make judgement calls.

IIRC, pretty much every time you hear unscheduled off world activation you immediately hear someone else say "close the iris"; if everyone is unconscious, no one can close the iris (it seems like the *Stargate* universe has never heard of a deadman's switch though).

On a separate note, the stun bomb rolled down the ramp for a good few seconds; it really should be standard procedure to shut the iris if something weird comes through the gate with no explanation, even if there was a valid code exchange.

Comment: Exactly right, the Iris doesn't auto-close, so the Wraith just walked through uncontested. As for closing the iris before the bomb went off, that would be a risk in itself. The IDC was valid, so despite the odd device, if they'd closed the iris then and there, they would have risked killing whoever came through the gate after it, which might have been SG-C or Atlantis personnel. Also, Teal'c and Ronan chased after the Wraith, so they would have died.

Comment: Even with a valid code having a strange device just roll through the gate with no warning or explanation would be a good start to a Foothold situation.  IIRC the iris is closed, the SGC receives a code, the SGC opens the iris and sends a clear to proceed signal, at some point a deadmans switch should have been implemented but i suppose that would have removed a fair amount of dramatic tension.

Comment: Ok. Why didn't they have an actual iris at Midway Station too? Obviously they assumed nobody could crack the dialing macro since no one even knew about the gate bridge ...wrong on both counts as it happens. Of course the out of universe answer being "so they can do this story."